# Call NodeJS program in a MediaWiki extension

Tags: node.js, mediawiki-extensions

I'm creating a MediaWiki extension to enable support for Argdown (https://argdown.org/) on my wiki. The Argdown parser is written in  NodeJS; what's the best way to have my extension's PHP file run a NodeJS program?

I see some examples on the web saying to do it with `exec`, but my sysadmin says that's a bad idea - he says `exec` creates security and performance problems. Is there a better way?

Comment: You could start a node process and communicate with it over some sort of [IPC mechanism](https://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node7.html) or even just over HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaWiki has a [shell framework](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Shell_framework) for just this purpose. After putting these at the top of my file...

```php
use MediaWiki\Shell\Shell;
use MediaWiki\Logger\LoggerFactory;
```

...here's what I put in my PHP function:

```php
global $IP;
$result = Shell::command( "/usr/local/bin/node", "$IP/extensions/Argdown/helloWorld.js" )->execute();
$stdout = $result->getStdout();
$stderr = $result->getStderr();
$ret = "<p>Stdout: $stdout</p>";
$ret .= "<p>Stderr: $stderr</p>";
return $ret;
```

I should be able to just put `"node"` instead of `"/usr/local/bin/node"`, but that's not working and I haven't figured out why yet - writing `node` on the command line works fine.

Thanks to the volunteers on the [MediaWiki Discord](https://discord.gg/ZrV2Ex9) for their help!